# Gradle: use of java pluggin classes task

Tags: gradle

`Gradle` java plugin offers a `classes` task, which describes

> "Assembles the production classes and resources directories."

what does it mean? what exactly it does.

One more task is `check`, it says

> All verification tasks in the project, including test.

what does this means? what are the other verification tasks apart from test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assembles the production classes and resources directories

It assembles under your build directory both class-files and resources, in the `classes` and `resources` folders accordingly. It depend on the `comlipe` and `processResources` tasks and make both of them run. That mean, that you can get the content, in your `build` folder, which later will be added into some archive (jar, war or ear) if you'll call some task to assemble it.

> what are the other verification tasks apart from test?

You can add some plugins to your build script, for example [checkstyle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/checkstyle_plugin.html) or [findbugs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/findbugs_plugin.html). This plugins add some additional verifications, such a static analysis of source code and etc. All this actions will be performed while `check` is executed.